# How can i receive all text content after download xml file with createObjectURL(blob)?

Tags: javascript

```
<a download="hello.xml" href='#' id="link">Загрузить</a>
<script>
var text = "<OPTP5101>Them-on-us Sale POS</OPTP5101><OPTP5102>Them-on-us Refund POS </OPTP5102>";
let blob = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
</script>
```

after download the file and open I've got just following

```
Them-on-us Sale POS
```

I need all text in xml file after downloading like that.

```
<OPTP5101>Them-on-us Sale POS</OPTP5101>
<OPTP5102>Them-on-us Refund POS </OPTP5102>
```

Is anybody know help me please!

Comment: Are you trying to open the xml with a browser? Try to open it with notepad and you would see the complete text. Your xml is not valid because it has multiple root element, a browser cannot render it correctly.

Comment: Thanks Ricky Mo. You right  it is displays only the content of the first tag in the browser, when i open with nodepad i see the complete text.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution when I added at the beginning and at the end of the text like this all displays when open with a browser

```
begining var text="<xml_cfg><global_params><param><name>OPTP</name><value>";
end text = text + "</value></param></global_params></xml_cfg>"
```

And the complete code looks like following

```
<a download="hello.xml" href="#" id="link">download xml</a>

<script language="JavaScript">
    var text="<xml_cfg><global_params><param><name>OPTP</name><value>";
    $.ajax({

        url: "rep.svxp_xml_download.download_xml_for_svxp",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{},
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        toastr.error("Произошла ошибка "+textStatus,"Информация", {"closeButton": true});
        return;
        },
        success: function(data){

        for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){

           text = text + "<" + data[i].optp + ">" + data[i].description + "</" + data[i].optp + ">";

        }
        text = text + "</value></param></global_params></xml_cfg>"

        let blob = new Blob([text], {type: "text/plain"});

        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }
 });

</script
```

> 